# python sqlite creation of a table syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on creating a new table within my database. I have done this before when creating other tables but this time I am facing a syntax error. As far as i can see, the syntax is correct. So, I cannot figure it out.

Below, there is a code snippet of the statement that is throwing the error:

```
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order(
    orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    productname STRING,
    productprice FLOAT,
    productquanitity INTEGER,
    producttotal INTEGER;''')
```

**This is the error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "N:/NEW/cashregister.py", line 42, in okitem
    producttotal INTEGER;''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "order": syntax error
```

I would be grateful for some suggestions on why this has occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved keyword in SQL; see the [documentation for the full list of reserved keywords that SQLite uses](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Use `"order"` to make SQLite understand that it is to be interpreted as a table name. You also forgot a closing `)`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order" (
    orderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    productname STRING,
    productprice FLOAT,
    productquanitity INTEGER,
    producttotal INTEGER
)
```

Comment: There's also a missing closing paren, which will be the next syntax error to pop up.

Comment: dont worry have found it